# jquery load() only once for one file

Tags: jquery, load

```
$("#documentProperties"+id).load("doctypes/"+selval+".jsp");
```

here selval is value of a dropdown option. dropdown options and the jsp's which i am loading
have the same names. that way i am using jquery's load() to load the jsp file into a div.

here problem is there are multiple div's which generate dynamically with name documentProperties and
a number attatched to it for id uniqueness. i need to load the jsp only once, if one jsp is already loaded
into a div don't load that, show any alert error saying this document is already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a class:

```
$("#documentProperties"+id + ":not(.loaded)").load("doctypes/"+selval+".jsp", function(){
  $(this).addClass('loaded');
});
```

EDIT:

```
var jspLoaded = [];
```

Later:

```
if (jspLoaded.indexOf(selval) === -1) {
  $("#documentProperties" + id).load("doctypes/" + selval + ".jsp", function() {
    jspLoaded.push(selval);
  });
}
```

Comment: it will just add a class to div, but how it would check whether the particular jsp is already loaded or not? i dont want to check which div is loaded but i want to check which jsp is loaded

Comment: instead of a class you could add a `data-selval` attribute with `selval` as value and before you call `load(...)` you check all your possible divs if one of them already has `el.data('selval') == selval`

Comment: Or you can keep track in an array e.g

Comment: can you please tell me little clearly, i actually didn't get that.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple solution but this will not work if your divs contains something (even if it's not jsp)

```
if($("#documentProperties"+id).html() == "")
     $("#documentProperties"+id).load("doctypes/"+selval+".jsp");
    else alert("Error");
```

You could use $.get and check if the content of the div is not equal to the result

```
$.get( "doctypes/"+selval+".jsp", function( data ) {
 if($("#documentProperties"+id).html() != data)
     $("#documentProperties"+id).html(data);
    else alert("Error");
});
```

Comment: No, html() will change based on the change of dropdown, different jsp's will load into my div on each change of option value. This will not work in my case. Thanks anyways..

Comment: So you are trying to load different jsp in one div, right?
The second option (with get), check if the jsp you're trying to load is the same as the jsp already loaded into the div

Comment: Not exactly the same div, the jsps may load into different divs, i need to check whether the jsp is loaded in the entire page or not..